# Get the identity value from an insert via a .net dataset update call

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, identity

Here is some sample code that inserts a record into a db table:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
da.Fill(ds, "Shippers")

Dim RowDatos As DataRow
RowDatos = ds.Tables("Shippers").NewRow
RowDatos.Item("CompanyName") = "Serpost Peru"
RowDatos.Item("Phone") = "(511) 555-5555"
ds.Tables("Shippers").Rows.Add(RowDatos)
Dim custCB As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
da.Update(ds, "Shippers")
```

It inserts a row in the Shippers Table, the ShippersID is
a Indentity value. My question is how can i retrieve the
Identity value generated when the new row is inserted in
the Shippers table.

I have done several web searches and the sources I've seen on the net don't answer it speccifically or go on to talk about stored procedures. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excellent article of some years ago that gives a perfect explanation as well as the demo hwow to achieve this. INcludes screenshots showing the process.

[MSDN article on data-adapter insert with returning the row-identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx#aspnet_tutorial01_dataaccesslayer_vb_topic5)

Cheers!

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SqlCommandBuilder, you could call a stored procedure to do the insert. In the stored procedure, you could return the `IDENTITY` value as an `OUTPUT` parameter.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(VS.71).aspx for an example.

Comment: or use scope_Identity() if you have an older version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDENT_CURRENT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx).

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT("Shippers") AS CurrentIdentityShippers;
```

Comment: very very bad choice
Ident_current gives the last identity inserted into the table from any connection. This is not the idntity just inserted by this porcess!